# subject of "be within striking distance"

Tags: phrase-meaning, subjects

Is the subject of "be within striking distance" necessarily an attacker if the phrase is understood literally? Are the following sentences all natural?

> a. The goat is within striking distance of the tiger.

> b. The tiger is within striking distance of its prey.

> c. The prey is within striking distance.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of "be within striking distance" can be both the attacker or the prey, all of the sentences given are natural. As seen [in Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/within-striking-distance):

> We live within striking distance of both Baltimore and Washington.

it is not necessary to refer to prey directly, it can be used as an idiom as well.